# nothin appears in the window created from basic C code using glut library on fedora 15

Tags: c, opengl, glut, fedora

I am trying to create a basic window with black background using glut library on fedora 15.

when execute the code, i simply get a window which has taken background as a screenshot of my original screen (not black screen).

I tried to use Forced FallBack mode but that too didn't help.

My Graphics:

```
lspci |grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 03)
```

openGl is correctly installed.

My sample code to generate window:

```
#include <GL/glut.h>

void display(void){

}

int main(int argc, char** argv){
 glutInit(&argc, argv);
 glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE|GLUT_RGBA);
 glutInitWindowSize(1024, 768);
 glutInitWindowPosition(100, 100);
 glutCreateWindow("Tutorial 01");
 glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
 glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
 glutDisplayFunc(display);
 glutMainLoop();
}
```

Any ideas why this is happening

Comment: the issue got resovled by adding glFlush() and glutSwapBuffers() in the display function()

Comment: Only the glutSwapBuffer() call is necessary, because you initialized the OpenGL context as double buffered (the GLUT_DOUBLE constant in the parameter of glutInitDisplayMode()). In this case OpenGL renders into the backbuffer of your window and the glutSwapBuffers() switch the visible and invisible buffer. The glFlush() call in your display callback is usually a bad habit, because it stalls the pipeline until all of the render calls before flush is sent to the device.

Comment: The call to `glClear(…)` should go at the beginning of `display` as well.